# Getting Java and TWAIN to play together nicely

Tags: java, java-native-interface, twain, image-scanner

I'm working on building an app to scan directly from TWAIN scanner to a Java applet. I'm already aware of [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) and [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/), but they cost money. I need free. I could re-invent the wheel with JNI, but it seems like someone has probably already done this as a FOSS tool.

Is anyone familiar with a **free** tool that can get a Java applet to read directly from a TWAIN scanner?

Answer (score 5):

Calling the TWAIN API from anything except C/C++ is going to be a major pain, it relies entirely on complicated C structures that you have to replicate exactly in memory. If you need only fairly basic scanning, you could use something like [GitHub site](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to call my old free 'EZTwain Classic' DLL (google for eztw32.dll)

Answer (score 3):

hm. I might have some homebrew available for it somewhere I could check, but for now: At our company, we basically gave up on this issue and implemented an (unfortunately win only) ActiveX solution: [Site Link](http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually purchased the chestysoft activeX control.  Been using it for about 3 years.  Works great but as with all ActiveX you are restricted to IE.  And this one is 32-bit only.
I'm looking into a flash approach now.  Since flash can capture from a camera why not from a scanner.  If I remember I'll report back what I find.

Comment: FYI, Flash is not the only solution to support IE 64 bit and other browsers. Dynamic Web TWAIN supports IE 32/64, Firefox, Chrome on Windows and Mac OS X.