# php script to acquire an image from a Twain source (scanner)

Tags: php, open-source, twain, image-scanner

i look a script that do this , that can acquire an image from scanner and upload it to server

i work in LAMP environment .

i know this company:

http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/twainupload.asp

Does anyone know free script (activeX) ?
Does anyone use a similar script ?

Comment: Here is a java one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338/getting-java-and-twain-to-play-together-nicely

Comment: here is one [demo](http://www.dynamsoft.com/demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx) that uses javascript at the client side and php at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of PHP systems that have Java bridges which would allow you to call out to Java objects. Zend has one and IBM has one (Project Zero).

If you have a good Java script and cannot find one for PHP, I would just call out via Java, or trigger the Java program and get the output back from it.

Jacob