# Web TWAIN scanning solution for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, twain, scanning

I know some of you will discourage scanning through a web page, unfortunately, it is a requirement.

I want to view my options in the situation, and maybe, some of you may have already gone through this and had a workable solution.

Problem is, we need to have a universal approach in scanning documents through the webpage without any external helper apps that does this for us.

I know this is a tall order, I would simply want to know the best next thing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this done with a Java applet successfully.  ActiveX might also work.

[Here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/twain-scan.html) is what appears to be a working TWAIN applet.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338/getting-java-and-twain-to-play-together-nicely) is question with answers related to TWAIN and Java.

Comment: That applet relies on a custom DLL being on the end user's computer.

Comment: It's still a potential jumping-off point.

Comment: thanks! i have to catch my Java lessons back then...

Comment: Customers have used our EZTwain library from Java but I'm not sure in a signed applet. The company that specializes in Java+TWAIN is Gnome with their Morena framework.  Hey, I can't put a hyperlink in a comment? Quelle bummer.

Comment: ActiveX of course works, you can check out this demo: www.dynamsoft.com/demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx. If you open it with IE, then it will ActiveX tech

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with just a browser and JavaScript, full stop, you'll need to include something else -- a Java applet, a .Net "No Touch Deployment" application (mostly IE-only), a Flash or Shockwave application, something like that.  In the Windows world, Flash has a huge installed base on browsers, but I don't know if it can do what you want (not knowing much about Flash).  Next up would be a signed Java applet.

The user will then need to give your thingy permission to access local resources, a process that varies depending on the technology used.  It's quite a simple process with a signed Java applet, much more involved and awkward for the end user with a .Net "No Touch Deployment" app.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) for implementing web scanning. It requires only that the user have Java installed. (With older versions of Java you can run out of memory when processing the scanned image. I had to cut large images into 100 pixel strips and send them individually to the server.)

Here's a small [scan-to-email project](http://scan2email.wanderingstan.com/) that I used Morena with.

Comment: i had problems with this one with scanner feeders.