# How I can access resources of local filesystem and manipulate them from browser

Tags: java, plugins, resize, filesystem-access

I need a technology to:

a) From the a browser, a web page, **browse to the user filesystem** (with his authorization)
b) Let user select a folder and search for images
c) The folder can contain **huge jpg images** (up to 20Mb)
d) **show a resized version**, very tiny version, of the founded images **inside the browser**
e) play with the thumbnail (reorder, rename, associate some options), interacting with the web pages
f) let the user select which image will be uploaded 
g) when finished **upload all the huge original** file size

I cannot use external client.
No problem for plugins.

Is there a technology out there capable to do this ?

I've decided to try to implement **in Java all the "local code"** (the folder and image selection, thumbnail creation) and pass thumbnail to the server. With an Ajax application pass the thumbnail to the web page where the applet reside and let the user interact with the thumbnail. At the end try to recall the applet to upload the original files.

Are there technological alternatives to this approach in your point of view ?

Comment: Access local files?  Is the point that your application is sandboxed, or why is this a problem?

Comment: @Charles Stewart I don't understand your question. The point is to access local images from web, resize locally to avoid bid upload times. With Java I can sign the applet and become a trusted entity and manipulate files low level. Only Java can do this ?

Comment: Ah!  I thought "browse to the user filesystem" meant browsing the local fs, and I was trying to imagin why that might be difficult...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already up on Java technologies, if you're happy to require that the end user have Java I'd go with a [signed Java applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html). You can use [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI)](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) for the image manipulation.

Comment: You are confirming me that Java can do this, but are there lnoinw and "simple" alternatives to Java ?

Comment: The answers to this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178892 I think anything you do is going to be a little bit complicated, because it's going to have to be signed or similar to assure users that they can allow it access to their system. I think a signed Java applet is a pretty simple way to do that, and Java has such rich library support, there's bound to be stuff to help with the various things you want to do. Good luck.