# Can you drag and drop a URL with a large icon/graphic from a web page to you desktop?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, cross-platform, cross-browser

Is there anyway to create a desktop icon (cross platform/browser) from a linked image on a page without some kind of executable?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="nice_icon.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not cross-platform, no, but most browsers support this out of the box. At least Firefox and IE do this no problem on Windows: When you drag-and-drop a link, a `.lnk` file is created on the desktop. I assume it's the same for Mac. For Linux, I don't know but I could imagine this works with the more modern graphical desktops as well.

There is no way to reliably enforce this across browsers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427566/creating-a-desktop-shortcut-using-a-web-page/2427619#2427619) (answered by yours truly)

Try it out!