# How to create a shortcut in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a shortcut that points to in-existing file in php and make it run normally in windows?

Example

```
makeshortcut("C:\Windows\calc.exe","short.lnk");
```

Then when I download the shortcut, it would open calc on my computer.

I don't have COM enabled, I do have exec() enabled, so I can run some kind of perl or python, however, lots of extensions are disabled, particlarly (pywin32 and win32::shortcut), so it would be highly appreciated if I can do this only in php or using calling another script with exec() which doesn't require me to install additional extensions.

Comment: Yeah! I forgot to mention that the file exist on the computer where the shortcut will be downloaded.

Comment: Is it in the same directory accross all computers you plan to do this? If so, just create a file manually in windows, upload to your server, and the pre-made file will be available on the site.

Comment: You need to figure out what the contents of a .lnk file are exactly and `echo` those contents; with a few HTTP headers set to initiate a file download. No existing filesystem level function is going to help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

The linux `ln` command has nothing to do with Windows .lnk files, and they are not compatible.

[Here is some info on the .lnk file format](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/LNK).

As you can see it is not trivial to create from scratch.

[liblnk](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Liblnk) library allows you to read .lnk files in Linux, but I haven't seen one that allows for their creation.

Edit:

Here is a SO question similar to yours:
[Generate Windows .lnk file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999256/generate-windows-lnk-file-with-php) and [Creating a Desktop Shortcut Using a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427566/creating-a-desktop-shortcut-using-a-web-page/2427619#2427619)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/index.en.html - a bash and c program to create a shortcut.
Compile the C program for your platform and call it with the `shell_exec` function.

Even if the question is old, I hope it helps others.