# How to save a website shortcut on your desktop using java script

Tags: javascript

How to save a website shortcut on your desktop using java script  ?

Comment: You mean, `Ctrl+S`?

Comment: please explain better your needs

Comment: I need a button that will save a shortcut of my website on my machine's desktop help with the code please

Comment: It's possible with IE and `Wscript.Shell` ActiveX object __only__, probably it's not what you're looking for. + No-one really should allow executing arbitrary ActiveXs via a web page.

Comment: And what if the client system does not have a desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript this is not possible, it is a security feature implemented by browsers. Spammy websites would abuse this feature.

Comment: [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509736/javascript-create-desktop-link-programmatically), second comment.

Comment: It is actually not impossible, since browsers can use [`beforeinstallprompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onbeforeinstallprompt) to create desktop shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible : adding to desktop is an OS thing ; JS through browser is not allow to do that. I might be wrong but I'll be surprised.

You can invite the user to do so in a nice enthusiastic modal though!