# Create shortcut to android/ ios' home screen/ desktop

Tags: shortcut

Thank you for your reply.

Sorry, my request was not clear. Here is the revision,
i am new to coding, i would like to know 
how to create a shortcut for a web app on a mobile Home screen and computer desktop by making a "CREATE SHORTCUT" button available for user to press, using a HTML script, compatible to mobile OS(Android & iOS) and Window respectively.

Users of my web app consists of majority of non tech-savvy individuals. This will help users, and me, eventually, especially reducing the explaining and training parts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - create desktop link programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509736/javascript-create-desktop-link-programmatically)

Comment: i have revised my question.