# how to scan image on php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i dont know its possible or no?

i have a project in php , 
can we scan image on php or javascript or ...  via scanner , is any way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but only using third-party plug-ins or applets, most of which are not free and limited to a platform (PC / Windows mostly, and some even to Internet Explorer, although there are ActiveX wrappers for other browsers, too.)

Check out the answers to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955855/usb-scanner-with-flex-java-applet/2007893#2007893). They should give you a good overview about what's possible.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that the scanner is connected to the server where PHP is being executed:*

Currently there's some good solutions to scan images through PHP by making use of the Open Source SANE Scanning software:

### [SCANPHP](http://code.google.com/p/scanphp/)

> A PHP Lightweight Scanning GUI which makes use of the Open Source SANE Scanning software. The PHP GUI can be installed on any Web Server as long as PHP can be run. PHP calls the scanimage command in order to provide the scan. Post scanning, the image is piped "|" to gocr / pnmtojpeg in order to provide the acquired file.

### [PHPSANE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/)

> phpSANE is a web-based frontend for SANE written in HTML/PHP so you can scan with your web-browser. It also supports OCR.

---

#### A code example would be:

```
exec("scanimage --mode Gray --resolution 150 | pnmtojpeg > /tmp/image.jpg");
```

You can refer to the [SANE Project Homepage](http://www.sane-project.org/) for further information on options available, installation steps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use scanner from the JavaScript on the client unless you have a special browser interface for that. No major browser have built-in support for that -- only via plugins.

Here is some more info:

- http://www.ciansoft.com/samples/tcxbrowser.htm
- http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/twainupload.asp